# SMTP sends email in bcc instead of the TO

Tags: python, email, smtp

I have been trying to send emails using SMTP but whenever I send an email it sends the email in bcc instead of sending the email in TO.

[the email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkM91.png)

```
import smtplib

my_email= 'exaMPle@gmail.com'
password= '333'
connection = smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com",465)
recive='recieve@gmail.com'
connection.ehlo()
connection.login(user=my_email,password=password)
connection.sendmail(my_email,to_addrs=recive,msg='Subject:msg \nhello')
connection.close()
```

Comment: You need a `To:` header.

Comment: See the [Example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtp-example) in the documentation.

Comment: The documentation has this clear note: **The *from_addr* and *to_addrs* parameters are used to construct the message envelope used by the transport agents. `sendmail` does not modify the message headers in any way.**

Comment: You need two newlines between the header and the message body.